# Laravel Sorting Data with Relationship and Pagination

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I need sorting the Records data according to Relationship.

I am trying below Query.

```php
$data = Lead::with('bdm', 'status_code', 'bdm.bdm')->get()->sortByDesc('bdm.bdm.name');
```

It works fine but I need data with pagination which is giving by Laravel 5 by default.

So If I am trying with below query . It is giving error.

```php
$data = Lead::with('bdm', 'status_code', 'bdm.bdm')->pagination(20)->sortByDesc('bdm.bdm.name');
```

I am trying an other way to do the same task. It works fine but it is not sorting the records.

```php
$data =  Lead::with(['bdm','status_code', 'bdm.bdm' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('name', 'desc');
        }])->paginate(20);
```

So kindly can anyone give me solution how to adjust this query.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: $data = Lead::with('bdm', status_code',bdm.bdm')->sortByDesc('bdm.bdm.name')->paginate(20);

are you seraching this one???

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately, It is not working.

Comment: Are you expecting the Leads to be ordered based on the name of the name of bdm.bdm? Because it will only order the grandchild relationship. Also I'd really recommend using more descriptive relationship names.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a `join` statement to do that.

If I were to assume your column names it should look something like this:

```php
$data =  Lead::with(['status_code', 'bdm.bdm'])
             ->join('bdms', 'bdms.id', '=', 'leads.bdm_id')
             ->orderBy('bdms.name', 'desc')
             ->paginate(20);
```

And the first `bdm` parameter in your query is redundant. It will be handled during `bdm.bdm` anyway.

Comment: Spectacular, i am amazed why techies did not vote for this stunning answer.